# Whats the difference in moment and moment.utc

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, utc

I've run the 2 commands `moment()` and `moment().utc()` and I don't see any difference in the output, except the UTC object, has a flag is UTC set to true.

Both return this - `Tue Oct 06 2020 20:02:33 GMT+0100`

What's the difference I should expect to be seeing and how can I test this?

I know UTC is a universal timecode format that shows an offset but I'm a bit confused by how it works here. An example and explanation would be very appreciated.

Comment: `moment()` is local time and `moment().utc()` is utc time

Comment: @aRvi can you provide me an example and explanation please? how could i see a difference in these 2? as in my output above there is no difference.

Comment: in your case, your UTC offset would be 0 that's why there is no difference in time

Comment: https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/ check this

Comment: Are you sure the offset would be 0? doesn't BST create an offset?

Comment: you can check your current offset  using `moment().utcOffset()`